# WPF: Bind TabControl SelectedIndex to a View Model's Enum Property

Tags: c#, wpf, model-view-controller

I have a property on my ViewModel that is an enum:

ViewModel:

```
public MyViewModel {

    // Assume this is a DependancyProperty
    public AvailableTabs SelectedTab { get; set; } 

    // Other bound properties
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property3 { get; set; }
}

public enum AvailableTabs {
    Tab1,
    Tab2,
    Tab3
}
```

I'd like to be able to bind SelectedIndex (or SelectedItem) of my TabControl to this property and have it correctly set the appropriate tab using a converter. Unfortunately, I'm a bit stuck. I know I can easily just use the SelectedIndex in my model, but I want the flexibility of re-ordering the tabs without breaking anything. I've given each TabItem a Tag property of the applicable enum value.

My XAML:

```
<TabControl Name="MyTabControl" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTab, Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}}">
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1" Tag="{x:Static local:AvailableTabs.Tab1}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 2" Tag="{x:Static local:AvailableTabs.Tab2}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property2}" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 3" Tag="{x:Static local:AvailableTabs.Tab3}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property3}" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to get the TabControl into my converter so I can do:

```
// Set the SelectedIndex via the enum (Convert)
var selectedIndex = MyTabControl.Items.IndexOf(MyTabControl.Items.OfType<TabItem>().Single(t => (AvailableTabs) t.Tag == enumValue));

// Get the enum from the SelectedIndex (ConvertBack)
var enumValue = (AvailableTabs)((TabItem)MyTabControl.Items[selectedIndex]).Tag;
```

I'm afraid I might be overthinking it. I tried using a MultiValue converter without much luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You simply need a converter that casts the value to an index.

```
public class TabConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
        return (int)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
        return (AvailableTabs)value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're assuming the index and enum values match. The idea is that I don't want to know the index. I want this to work without code changes if I change the order of the tab items later in XAML.

Comment: Then you'll have to bind to something other than SelectedIndex.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the values in the XAML, I would bind ItemsSource to an array of values from your enum:

Code:

```
public AvailableTabs[] AvailableTabs => Enum.GetValues(typeof(AvailableTabs Enum)).Cast<AvailableTabs>().ToArray();
```

XAML:

```
<TabControl Name="MyTabControl" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTab}" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableTabs}" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure what that would accomplish. My TabItems aren't enum values. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: According to the code you posted in the original question, your tabs are identified by the AvailableTabs enum.   What I am recommending is to not put any TabItems directly in to Xaml.  Instead, bind itemsSource to the array of possible values.  THis will make your code simpler to write and maintain, because it will change automatically when you update the enum.  (I edited my answer to reflect how your code would actually look with this approach.)

Comment: I don't think we're on the same page. My TabItems have Gridviews, textboxes, etc. They are just ellipsed out for the example. I simply want the view model to be able to pre-select what tab is shown by default when the model is bound to the window. Envision my view model having 9 properties that are bound to 3 controls on each tab. Like I said, I can do it easily just binding to a property called SelectedIndex, but then I'm stuck having to know the order of the tab items. It's much easier to say MyViewModel.SelectedTab = AvailableTabs.Tab2 when building the viewmodel.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question.  Perhaps it would be a simpler approach to use content templates for the tab control and have a model that exposes the property and the AvailableTags enum value for the item.

Answer (score 0):

- The important thing is that the solution should work if I change the tab order in the TabControl

  - if this is not important then the elements in the enum type

    - and the views in the TabControl have to be in the same order

      - the conversion in this case is to cast the enum value to int value
- I name the views in TabControl according to enum values

  - AppTab.ValidDates (enum value) corresponds to validDatesView (view name)

    - enum values

      ```
          public enum AppTab
          {
              Parameters, ValidDates, ...
          }
      ```
    - views in TabControl

      ```
          <TabControl Name="myTabControl" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTab, Converter={c:AppTabToIntConverter}}" 
                      IsEnabled="{Binding IsGuiEnabled}">
              <TabItem Header="{x:Static r:Resource.Parameters}">
                  <view:ParametersView x:Name="parametersView"/>
              </TabItem>
              <TabItem Header="{x:Static r:Resource.Dates}">
                  <view:ValidDatesView x:Name="validDatesView"/>
              </TabItem>
      ```
- fill up ViewNameIndexDictionary and IndexViewNameDictionary

  - Window_Loaded event is too late, AppTabToIntConverter runs before that

    ```
          public static Dictionary<AppTab, int> ViewNameIndexDictionary { get; set; }  = new Dictionary<AppTab, int>();
          public static Dictionary<int, AppTab> IndexViewNameDictionary { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, AppTab>()

          private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              var i = 0;
              foreach (TabItem item in myTabControl.Items)
              {
                  var tabContentName = ((FrameworkElement)item.Content).Name;
                  // Convert TabItem name "validDatesView" to "ValidDates"
                  var appTabString = tabContentName.FirstCharToUpper().CutLastNCharacter("View".Length);
                  var appTab = (AppTab)Enum.Parse(typeof(AppTab), appTabString);
                  ViewNameIndexDictionary.Add(appTab, i);
                  IndexViewNameDictionary.Add(i, appTab);
                  i++;
              }
          }
    ```
- the converter

  ```
        // The root tag must contain: xmlns:c="clr-namespace:LedgerCommander.ValueConverter"
        class AppTabToIntConverter : BaseValueConverter<AppTabToIntConverter>
        {
            public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (!(value is AppTab appTab))
                    throw new Exception("The type of value is not AppTab");
                return MainWindowView.ViewNameIndexDictionary[appTab];
            }

            public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (!(value is int tabIndex))
                    throw new Exception("The type of value is not int");
                return MainWindowView.IndexViewNameDictionary[tabIndex];
            }
        }
  ```
- the BaseValueConverter (thanks to AngelSix)

  ```
   public abstract class BaseValueConverter<T> : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter where T : class, new()
   {
    private static T Converter = null;

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Converter ?? (Converter = new T());
    }

    public abstract object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);

    public abstract object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);
  ```

  }